# The Type Or Name Space name Could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting these errors in Unity

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvVU2.png)

pertaining to these two C# scripts

This C# script is the file Tiles.cs

```
public class tile{

public enum Tiletype {empty, Floor };

Tiletype type = Tiletype.empty;

StandaloneObject standaloneObject;
InstalledObject installedObject;

World world;
int x;
int y;

public Tile (World world, int x, int y ) {
    this.world = world;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

This C# script is the file World.cs

```
public class World {

Tile[,] tiles;
int width;
int height;

public World(int width = 100, int height = 100 ) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    
    tiles = new Tile[width,height];
    
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            tiles[x,y] = new Tile(this, x, y);
        }
    }
}
public Tile GetTileAt (int x, int y) {
    if (x > width || x < 0 || y > height || y < 0) {
        Debug.Debug.LogError("Tile ("+x+", "+y+") is out of range.");
        return null;
    }
return tiles [x, y];
}
```

}

I am on Unity 2021.3.16f1
Please point out the mistake(s) i made resulting in the errors and how to resolve the issues

Comment: `tile != Tile` Decide what to name your class and use that consistently. Case matters.

Comment: @RetiredNinja oh such a simple mistake on my part thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `public class tile` to `public class Tile` in your Tiles.cs. Your code is referencing that class as `Tile` but because class names are case sensitive and you have it lowercase `tile` the compiler can't find that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can type "public void Tile" if you dont have [return] statement in your function. (as in world method)

Also, if your classes are in different namespaces you should have "using" namespace above your class.

Maybe problem in case sensitive names tile and Tile